# unable to read the data after write operation using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, arduino, core-bluetooth

Am new to Objective C Am trying to read data from an arduino peripheral with a specific service and characteristic

there are two characteristics with for two different services

```
//arduino code

BLEService dataService("938548e6-c655-11ea-87d0-0242ac130003"); //Data reading
BLEService ledService("19B10000-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1214"); //LED control service


// Initialize dataService characteristics
BLECharacteristic dataArray("77539407-6493-4b89-985f-baaf4c0f8d86", BLERead | BLENotify, 114); // standard 16-bit characteristic UUID

// Initialize ledService characteristics
BLECharacteristic eventChar("19B10001-E8F2-537E-4F6C-D104768A1213", BLERead | BLEWrite, 1);
```

I was able to notify and got the read value for the first characteristics for when am trying to write for second characteristic am not receiving data from peripheral

```
    for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service. characteristics) {
        NSLog(@"Charecteristics %@", characteristic.UUID);
       
        if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString containsString: @"77539407"]) {
            NSLog(@"Specific Characteristics %@", characteristic.UUID);
//Working........ Characteristic 
            [peripheral setNotifyValue: YES forCharacteristic: characteristic];
        }
            if ([characteristic.UUID.UUIDString containsString: @"19B10001"]) {
                NSLog(@"Specific Charecteristics %@", characteristic.UUID);
                NSData *data = [@"01" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"WRITING DATA");
                NSLog(@"%@ : dataaaaaa",data);
                [peripheral writeValue: data forCharacteristic: characteristic
                type: CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
            }
        }
```

after writing the data it goes to the **didWriteValueForCharacteristic** where I get null for the writeCallBack can someone explain me what mistake am doing

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didWriteValueForCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didWrite");
    
    NSString *key = [self keyForPeripheral: peripheral andCharacteristic:characteristic];
    NSLog(@" writeCallback : %@ ",key);
    RCTResponseSenderBlock writeCallback = [writeCallbacks objectForKey:key];
    
    NSLog(@" writeCallback : %@ ",writeCallback);
    
    if (writeCallback) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
            [writeCallbacks removeObjectForKey:key];
            writeCallback(@[error.localizedDescription]);
        } else {
            if ([writeQueue count] == 0) {
                NSLog(@"NO 1");
                [writeCallbacks removeObjectForKey:key];
                writeCallback(@[]);
            }else{
                // Remove and write the queud message
                NSLog(@"NO 2");
                NSData *message = [writeQueue objectAtIndex:0];
                [writeQueue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
                [peripheral writeValue:message forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
            }
            
        }
    }
    
}
```

**Below image is the log**

[OUTPUT LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B35lv.jpg)

Comment: did you mean to tag this as react-native? If so I recommend using react-native-ble-plx and performing the task in JS/TS rather than objective-c, it's much easier to work with (and also works on Android). I've had success with that on other projects.

Comment: What is `keyForPeripheral: andCharacteristic:`?

Comment: -(NSString *) keyForPeripheral: (CBPeripheral *)peripheral andCharacteristic:(CBCharacteristic *)characteristic {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@|%@", [peripheral uuidAsString], [characteristic UUID]];
}

@Larme

Comment: Could you also print `writeCallbacks`? To see if it's there really? When is saved the callback?

Comment: this is what I got @Larme when I tried to print 
NSLog(@" writeCallback : %@ ",writeCallbacks);

writeCallbacks : {}
2022-05-23 17:47:21.461132+0530 App[17936:1147848]  writeCallback : {
}

Comment: So `writeCallbacks` is empty, so that's why `[writeCallbacks objectForKey:key]` returns `nil`. So when did you save one callback into `writeCallbacks`?